# how to continue grouping until end of line uisng regex? regex101 code in comment

Tags: regex

[image]

(image) how to find the green highlight part using regex?

regex101
https://regex101.com/r/knSRpd/3

where i think the problem lay at: is i used the lookahead to find the next line that didnt start with Tab.
what I had tried:
^(?!\t)(^(FULL|SMALL))?(\S.\n$)?(\S.*?)(?=^(?!\t)\w+?|$(?!\n))

I tried to find the string sentence in between with end of line at \n (\S.\n$)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all lines after FULL or SMALL that do not start with a tab:

```
^(FULL|SMALL)\b(.*(?:\n(?!\t).*)*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(FULL|SMALL)\b` Capture either FULL or SMALL in **group 1**
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
  - `(?:\n(?!\t).*)*` Optionally repeat matching the next lines if they don't start with a tab
- `)` Close the non capture group

In the replacement, use group `$1` and group `$2`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wTni8j/1)

If you only want to match lines that start with a non whitespace char to prevent matching empty lines

```
^(FULL|SMALL)\b(.*(\n\S.*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hnTyZY/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
/^(FULL|SMALL)\b(.*(?:\n(?!\t|FULL\b|SMALL\b).*)*)/gm
/^(FULL|SMALL)\b(.*(?:\n(?!\t).*)*)/gm
```

The replacement will need adjusting (since there are just two capturing groups in the pattern now) to

```js
<div class="PANEL $1">\n<div class="action">$2</div></div>\n\n
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LQIXNX/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(FULL|SMALL)\b` - `FULL` or `SMALL` as whole words
- `(.*(?:\n(?!\t|FULL\b|SMALL\b).*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `(?:\n(?!\t|FULL\b|SMALL\b).*)*` - zero or more lines that do not start with a TAB, `FULL` or `SMALL` as whole words. If you use `(?!\t)`, the checks for `FULL` and `SMALL` will not be triggered and even if the line starts with these words, it will get consumed.